# Problem with count the decimal part by C++?

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm a newbie in C++. I got trouble when count the decimal part by C++, here is the example and code:

example:

```
   3.01: count of decimal part is 2
103.939: count of decimal part is 3
```

code:

```
int result = 0;
double d   = 4.01;

while(true) {
    cout << "(int)d: " << (int)d << endl;
    if(d == (int)d) break;

    d *= 10;
    cout << "d *= 10: " << d << endl;

    result++;
}
cout << result << endl;
```

console:

```
int(d): 4
d *= 10: 40.1
int(d): 40
d *= 401
int(d): 400
d *= 10: 4010
int(d): 4009
...
```

what happens to **4.01**? And the same strange result when the **double = 5.01** etc. I know it's the problem of precision when convert **DOUBLE** to **INT**, but I'm really curious about how it happens when the test doubles like 4.01, 5.01, etc.

And in addition, how to modify the ***if state*** correct to test 4.01?

Comment: When you do `double d = 4.01;`, the value of `d` is not 4.01. It's a number very close to 4.01. Important reading: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken

Comment: Hint. The closest `double` to `4.01` is `4.0099999999999997868371792719699442386627197265625`. Nothing particularly strange here. After all, most folk are happy with the fact that the closest `int` to `4.01` is `4`. One way round this is to round your number to 14 significant figures, and output only those digits, writing something clever to not print trailing zeros.

Comment: Got it! Guys! Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since your question has been answered in the comments, I am posting a *different* approach to count decimal digits ( **`by taking input as string`** and treating the entire thing as string operation ).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string d;
    cin>>d;
    
    int flag=0, count=0, pos;
    
    for(int i = 0 ; i < d.length() ; i++){
        if(d[i]=='.'){
            flag = 1; 
            pos = i;  // for keeping the index of decimal point
            continue;
        }
        
        if(flag==1){
            count++;
        }
        
    }
    

    // for removing trailing zeroes like 0.10000 is actually 0.1
    if(flag==1){
        for(int i=d.length()-1;i>pos;i--){
            
            if(d[i]!='0'){
                break;
            }
            
            if(d[i]=='0'){
                count--;
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    cout<<count<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

**`UPD 1.0`** : Taken input as double as asked by frank.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    
    double num;
    
    string d;
    cin>>num;
    
    d = to_string(num);
    
    int flag=0, count=0, pos;
    
    for(int i = 0 ; i < d.length() ; i++){
        if(d[i]=='.'){
            flag = 1; 
            pos = i;  // for keeping the index of decimal point
            continue;
        }
        
        if(flag==1){
            count++;
        }
        
    }
    

    // for removing trailing zeroes like 0.10000 is actually 0.1
    if(flag==1){
        for(int i=d.length()-1;i>pos;i--){
            
            if(d[i]!='0'){
                break;
            }
            
            if(d[i]=='0'){
                count--;
            }
            
        }
    }
    
    cout<<count<<"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks anyway. However, the input of my code must be double.

Comment: Updated the code, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: the benefit with string is you can also take a value which is outside of double range, and still count the digits without storing the result in a variable ( like is done for int/long)

Answer (score 0):

Check this code out. It worked for me.

```
int result = 0;
int f = 1;
double d = 4.01;
while((int)(d*f)!=d*f)
{
    f*=10;
    result++;
}
std::cout<<result;
```

Output:

```
2
```